# Rscript Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds

Tags: r, linux

The following `R` script can run as expected on Windows. However, on Linux, using the command `Rscript`, it returns the error:

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") :
  Timeout was reached: Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
Calls: read_html -> read_html.default
Execution halted
```

The code has set `options(timeout= 4000000)`, but why still timed out? Why the same code can run correctly on Windows?  How to address this issue?

By the way, the script was run normally on the same Linux machine one week ago.

```
#start
library(data.table)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
library(mailR)

options(timeout= 4000000)

ranktitle <- read.csv("/tmp/title.csv",header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
i <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,15)

crawler <- data.frame()
basicURL <- "http://www.xiaohulu.com/rank/?plat="
for (m in i){
  date <- Sys.Date()
  urldate <- date-1
  #url list loop
  url <- str_c(basicURL,m)

  web <- read_html(url,encoding = "UTF-8")
  #read html code

  platformdata <- web %>% html_nodes("dd") %>%  html_text()
  #read platformname

  platform <- web %>% html_nodes("h2")  %>%  html_text()
  #read ranknum

  platformdata <- platformdata[(1:16)]
  platform <- rep(platform,16)
  #adjust platformname
  datelist <- rep(urldate,16)
  #adjust datelist

  crawlera <- data.frame(datelist,ranktitle,platform,platformdata)
  #write into dataframe
  crawler <- rbind(crawler,crawlera)
}
#wirtefile
csvFileName <- paste("/tmp/results/platform",date,".csv",sep="")
write.csv(crawler,file = csvFileName)
```

The content of the '`title.csv`':

```
title
礼物价值
礼物价值
礼物价值
礼物价值-1
弹幕条数
弹幕条数
弹幕条数
弹幕条数-1
```

Comment: This is not a minimal example, nor is it even runnable without your `/tmp/title.csv` file

Comment: @Spacedman I didn't put it since it contains Chinese characters. Now it is put.

Comment: Read the help for `options` and it says the timeout is for "some Internet operations". You are using `read_html` which is a third-party add on and has no obligation to obey the timeout setting. Maybe it works on Windows and not Linux because that Linux box is being blocked by the server for some reason, or has a broken network configuration.